# ADD command failing while building dockerfile using docker-build-step plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

The following is my DockerFile

```
FROM centos:centos6
MAINTAINER Priyanka

################## Helpful utils
RUN yum -y install sudo
RUN yum -y install curl
RUN yum -y install unzip

################## JDK7

#Note that ADD uncompresses this tarball automatically
ADD jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt
WORKDIR /opt/jdk1.7.0_79
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java 1
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/jar 1
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javac 1
RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_79" >> /etc/environment
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Xms1024m -Xmx4196m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m

################## TOMCAT

#Note that ADD uncompresses this tarball automatically
ADD apache-tomcat-7.0.67.tar.gz /usr/share
WORKDIR /usr/share/
RUN mv  apache-tomcat-7.0.67 tomcat7
RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_79/" >> /etc/default/tomcat7
RUN groupadd tomcat
RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -g tomcat tomcat
RUN chown -Rf tomcat.tomcat /usr/share/tomcat7
EXPOSE 8087

################## ROC Client War Download

RUN curl -O http://10.113.57.164:8080/job/ROC4.0_Client/ws/spark-web/entrypoint/target/entrypoint.war
RUN unzip entrypoint.war -d /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/roc_client
ADD validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/roc_client/WEB-INF/lib/
ADD validation-api-1.1.0.Final-sources.jar /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/roc_client/WEB-INF/lib/
RUN rm /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/roc_client/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar 
RUN rm /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/roc_client/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar

################## Tomcat launch

CMD ["/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh","run"]
```

On building this file using docker-build-step in Jenkins the build fails with the following exception at ADD

```
Step 0 : FROM centos:centos6

 ---> 3bbbf0aca359

Step 1 : MAINTAINER Priyanka

 ---> Using cache

 ---> c8055ba8439a

Step 2 : RUN yum -y install sudo

 ---> Using cache

 ---> 203da82ad2af

Step 3 : RUN yum -y install curl

 ---> Using cache

 ---> c6cb08257236

Step 4 : RUN yum -y install unzip

 ---> Using cache

 ---> 688620db641a

Step 5 : ADD jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt

ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonString
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.cmd.CreateImageCommand.execute(CreateImageCommand.java:139)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:75)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonString
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl.getJsonString(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:194)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl.getString(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:199)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.cmd.CreateImageCommand$1.callback(CreateImageCommand.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.cmd.CreateImageCommand.readJsonStream(CreateImageCommand.java:161)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.cmd.CreateImageCommand.execute(CreateImageCommand.java:115)
    ... 10 more
Build step 'Execute Docker command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have run this build many times and it ran successfully without any problem.I made some temporary changes to build configuration and reverted back. Since then it is throwing this  error.
Tried removing off all the docker commands from the File and retained just one RUN command.Still the same issue.It is not able to run any docker commands.

Comment: Just in case it is a cache issue, try rebuilding without cache (`docker build --no-cache`)

Comment: You should not abuse of `RUN` and perform the different installations (utils, JDK7, TOMCAT) with one sole `RUN`, thus decreasing the number of layers, this decreasing the disk space needed. See some example here: https://github.com/jfrazelle/dockerfiles

Comment: Ok. But will that help resolve the issue?.Tried removing off all the docker commands from the File and retained just one RUN command.Still the same issue.It is not able to run any docker commands.

Comment: What command do you use to build that Dockerfile? (I don't understand why there is a java exception considering docker is written in go)

Comment: I am not invoking the docker command myself. The jenkin's docker-build-step-plugin,which is written in java does that for me.Tried executing the command myself which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Actually the file you are looking for does not exists into your workspace job directory. If your docker-step-plugin could find the file, the command ADD from yout Dockerfile will work :-)
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is fairly old, however I ran into this issue and found a different solution which may help others who find this question in the future.

In my case, I'm using devicemapper as the storage driver, and the Logical Volume containing the thinpool had hit 90% full, at which point it triggers an alarm when trying to create a new image.  This was causing the Jenkins Docker Plugin to fail with the same stack trace posted above.

Removing old images from the image store fixed the problem.